# Laravel 5.2 route with multiple parameters

Tags: php, laravel-5

UPDATE: thanks for the suggestions below. The URL works ok when I hit it from the browser directly. The suggestion below in terms of syntax which I understood as correct is:

```
{{ route('my.route', ['p1' => $var1, 'p2' => $var2, 'p3' => $var3]) }}
```

But I can see this in inspect being resolved as:

```
http://my.url/theroute/var1?var2=xxx&var3=yyy
```

The route format is not being generated correctly, and the variables are being passed as URL parameters rather than being part of the URL like this:

```
http://my.app/var1/var2/var3
```

Also, I want to use named route, and not hard code the URL. If I hard code it, it works OK. What have I missed? Thanks!

---

I have a route in my Laravel app that looks like this:

```
http://my.app/{p1}/{p2}/{p3}
```

The route is named `my.route` in the routes list.

In `Blade` I am trying to open this route. How do I do this. I have tried unsuccessfully:

```
{{ route(['my.route', $var1, $var2, $var3]) }}
```

also

```
{{ route(['my.route', 'p1' => $var1, 'p2' => $var2, 'p3' => $var3]) }}
```

also

```
{{ route('my.route', ['p1' => $var1, 'p2' => $var2, 'p3' => $var3]) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in my route definition. I had another route that conflicted with the one I was trying to access. Thanks for all the help!

The correct syntax was:

```
route('my.route', [$var1, $var2, $var3])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ route('my.route', ['p1' => $var1, 'p2' => $var2, 'p3' => $var3]) }}
```

Above is correct. But i think you can't use my.route as route name , remove dot and place underscore.

Or just use the url as plain text.
href='/my.app/'{p1}/{p2}/{p3}

See here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes

Comment: Dots in route names are fine.

Comment: Also try to hit the url from browser directly and see if any error occurs there.